Ruby: How can I return a logical operator like && or ||
I am building a rules engine and I would like to dynamically update my logical operators. Because of this I'd like to return the && or || from a method. But I'm having a heck of a time doing this. How can I?
This is a basic example of what I'm trying to do:
module Rules::Engine
  module_function

  def call
    a = true
    b = false
    ap "what does this return #{a logic b}"
  end

  def logic(a)
    if a
      return &&
    else
      return ||
    end
  end

end


Short answer: You can't. Logical operators are not methods and as such you are not going to be able to pass them around. You could instead just pass both arguments to your logic method and return the value from there. e.g .def logic(a,b); a ? a && b : a || b; end. Another alternative would be to wrap your arguments in a class and then define logical methods for them such as and and or (or whatever names you would choose) then you can simply call the methods on the receiver and pass arguments as necessary.

Try this:


module Rules::Engine
  module_function
  def call
    a = true
    b = false
    operator = logic(a)

    puts a.send(operator, b)
  end

  def logic(and_operator)
    and_operator ? :& : :|
  end
end



You can also use eval, instead of send, but it's not recommended by rubocop

This works with the given a and b, so assuming those objects are always TrueClass,  FalseClass, or NilClass this will work as desired. This will also "work" (meaning it won't error out) if a is compatible with the transmission of the :& method as well as with the receipt of b as an argument. Whether or not 0 is an acceptable response given a=1 and b=2, I guess would be left up to the OP but it definitely differs from 1 && 2 #=> 2
